# Android CardView Not Displaying Content

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to simply place a `TextView` inside a `CardView`, but to no avail. All I need to do is make two numbers appear inside the two `CardViews`. At the moment, with code below, the two `CardViews` appear, but do not show any text / content inside them.

I have tried many different combinations but none seem to be working! Placing the `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` does not work, nor does making it a direct child of the `CardView`.

Here's my current code:

```
calendar_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hoo.box.facecalendar.SquareCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_view_day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</hoo.box.facecalendar.SquareCardView>
```

---

```
SquareCardView.java

public class SquareCardView extends CardView {
    public SquareCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }
}
```

---

```
CalendarAdapter.java

public class CalendarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarAdapter.CalendarViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Date curDate;
    private List<Date> dateList;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        curDate = new Date();
        dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    }

    @Override
    public CalendarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_view, viewGroup, false);
        CalendarViewHolder viewHolder = new CalendarViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CalendarViewHolder calendarViewHolder, int i) {
        if (dateList.size() <= i) {
            Date tempDate = new Date(curDate);
            tempDate.addDays(i + 1);
            dateList.add(i, tempDate);
        }
        Date iDate = dateList.get(i);
        calendarViewHolder.TEXTVIEW.setText(Integer.toString(iDate.day));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return dateList.size() + 1; }

    class CalendarViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView TEXTVIEW;
        public final SquareCardView CARDVIEW;

        public CalendarViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            TEXTVIEW = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view_day);
            CARDVIEW = (SquareCardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view_card);
        }
    }
}
```

Just a prior thanks to anyone who can help me! This has been eating away at me for days!

Comment: Is all of this code relevant? It would probably be enough to show us just the code of where you create the CardView and the effort in placing a TextView in it.

Comment: Well the thing is, I don't know where on **earth** I'm wrong. I thought that it may have been a problem with the adapter at one stage.

Comment: Have a look at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [sscce](http://sscce.org/) on how to produce a minimal version of the code that reproduces the error or difficulty you're facing. Posting the whole code and expecting us to go through every single line doesn't make our life easy. Some may not even appreciate the lack of effort shown. After trying a few things, it may still be the case you have no idea where the error is coming from, but you can document your attempts, so we don't repeat the same steps in vain.

Comment: I cant see anything wrong in your CardView, except that `android:orientation="vertical"` does not mean anything for CardView.

Also, in your adapter, you are changing your backing array which you should not do. On top of that, if you are trying to add items as RV scrolls, add a scroll listener to do so instead. In addition to that, you need to call `adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, count)` so that recycler view knows that your adapter size changed. Trying to call that method during an onBind method will receive IllegalStateException as adapter contents cannot change during layout calc.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the `android:orientation`! That eliminates one thing, but does not fix the issue. Also, I am aware of the issues with the adapter, but decided to first focus on getting text to display in the `CardView` at all.

Comment: Did you check with hierarchy viewer? Or, do you see the text view if you enable "show layout bounds" from developer options ?

Comment: This is what I see with 'Show Layout Bounds': https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0BTCg8hydMIYzNCbzBpV2FwejA/edit?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 3 hours of playing with it, I found the solution! It was a problem with `SquareCardView`'s `onMeasure()` not resizing the inner layout bounds. Below is what I altered it to:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your support library which you are using for cardview. The compiled sdk version and support lib version should be same.

for example:
In build.gradle

if compileSdkVersion 23  then

in dependencies you should use

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'

Check both the versions in build.gradle.

ps: if you use support lib version 24 studio suggest you the following

"this support library should not use a different version (24) than the compilesdkversion (23)"

best luck !

Comment: There is already an answer verified why you are putting your thoughts "there might be..." this does not seems to be an actual attempt of answering the question.